# Black screen, lightdm not starting after upgrading to 19.10

Tags: boot, lightdm, 19.10

This morning I decided to upgrade Ubuntu. The upgrade itself seemed to be successful, however after rebooting I ended up seeing a black screen. I am able to log in to non-graphical desktops though. The problem seems to be with lightdm.

[image]

[image]

After browsing the internet about this issue, someone suggested purging and reinstalling xorg and lightdm packages. The purge went fine, however I can no longer install xorg back because of several unmet dependencies.

Nothing in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/162075/170086) seemed to mention my problem either. I wish I never had initiated this update.

When I try installing xorg again or gdm3 they seem to depend on libgl1 at some point in their dependency tree, which depends on libglx0 -> libglx-mesa0 -> libglapi-mesa(= 19.2.1-1Ubuntu1), however this last package is already installed but with a different version: (1:19.2~git190512201800.974c4d6~b~padoka0)

Comment: make a liveusb then boot from it and try and copy the lightdm files from the usb to your system the files are at "/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/*.conf"
"/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/*.conf"
"/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf"

Comment: Making a live USB just to get some package files seems like an overkill to me. There's probably some repository that I can straight up download those files. Besides, I'd probably need to borrow someone's laptop to make the live USB in the first place.